# Writing a binary file into ASCII code using C

Tags: c, ascii

I am trying to read a binary file and write it into ASCII format.
I have written a basic program using C. It reads binary file but writes in binary not in ASCII code.

How do I write binary file in ASCII code/format?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
  main ( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
  {
  FILE *fs, *ft ;
    char ch ;
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
    puts ( "Improper number of arguments" ) ;
    exit(1) ;
    }
    fs = fopen ( argv[1], "rb" ) ;
     if ( fs == NULL )
    {
    puts ( "Cannot open source file" ) ;
    exit(1) ;
      }
   ft = fopen ( argv[2], "w" ) ;
    if ( ft == NULL )
   {
   puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
      fclose ( fs ) ;
    exit(1) ;
    }
    while ( 1 )
    {
      ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
     if ( ch == EOF )
    break ;
     else
    fputc ( ch, ft ) ;
      }
     fclose ( fs ) ;
     fclose ( ft ) ;
   }
```

here I upload my .g binary file screen shoot

ctrlv.in/428546 
You can download from 
http://www.fileswap.com/dl/KU3xlwTI9d/

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert the binary to hexadecimal representation?

Comment: If your binary file (all files are "binary files", frankly) is already an ASCII file, then there's no conversion to be done. If it's not, then you'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "conversion", i.e. what are you converting *from*?

Comment: What do you mean "text format" - please show sample of expected output for 3-byte file  - `{ 1, 13, 65 }`.

Comment: Generally best not to `#include <cstdlib>` in a C program, too.

Comment: Actually, I want to convert .g file which is a binary data file of BRL-CAD.

Comment: @user3717474: So once again, what do you want the "text file" to look like? Specifically how to you want to represent the contents of that file as text? Can you provide a sample input file, along with what you want the output file to look like?

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/KU3xlwTI9d/ here is my binary file in .g format. It can be represented in any text form.

Comment: If "any text form" will do, then `int main(void) { puts("haha!"); }` and you're done. Or open it up in a hex editor and take a screenshot. Otherwise, you'll have to provide a bit more information.

Comment: http://ctrlv.in/428546     here I upload a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention in the comments that "any text form" will do, here's a way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if ( argc != 3 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You need two arguments.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE * infile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if ( !infile ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE * outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if ( !outfile ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file: %s\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int ch;
    while ( (ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF ) {
        fprintf(outfile, "%x", ch);
    }
    fputc('\n', outfile);

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sample session:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ hexdump binfile
0000000 6854 7369 6920 2073 6874 2065 7564 626d
0000010 7365 2074 7571 7365 6974 6e6f 4920 7627
0000020 2065 6573 6e65 0a2e                    
0000028
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./bin2txt binfile txtfile
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ cat txtfile
54686973206973207468652064756d62657374207175657374696f6e2049277665207365656e2ea
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

`txtfile` now contains a text representation of the contents of `bin file`.

EDIT: All kidding aside, I'm not sure you really understand what you mean by "binary", and "text", here. Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE * numfile = fopen("file.num", "wb");
    if ( !numfile ) {
        perror("Couldn't open file.num for writing");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE * txtfile = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if ( !txtfile ) {
        perror("Couldn't open file.txt for writing");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int num = 0x0a216148;
    fprintf(txtfile, "Ha!\n");
    fwrite(&num, sizeof(num), 1, numfile);

    fclose(numfile);
    fclose(txtfile);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, we've got a program that creates two files - a text file containing the text `"Ha!\n"`, and a binary file containing the number `0x0a216148` in hex, or `169,959,752` in decimal. So let's run it, and take a look at those files:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./mkfiles
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ cat file.txt
Ha!
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ cat file.num
Ha!
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

What's going on? It turns out that the ASCII characters for `'H'`, `'a'`, `'!'` and `'\n'` come out to `0x48`, `0x61`, `0x21` and `0x0a`. When you string them together, you get `0x4861210a` which, on a little-endian architecture, is exactly the same way you represent the number `169,959,752` in a four-byte `int`.

So, if you have a binary file containing `0x48`, `0x61`, `0x21` and `0x0a`, and you want to "translate it into text", then you tell me - do we translate it as "Ha!", or do we translate it as "One hundred and sixty nine million, nine hundred and fifty nine thousand, seven hundred and fifty two"?

As you will hopefully see, there is no way of answering this unless you know what I had in mind when I created that file. I could have meant either. Or I could have meant something else entirely, such as a 32 bit RGBA value. When different things can be encoded in the same way, then you have to know what encoding I was using if you want to decode it.

So it makes no sense at all to ask "how do I translate a binary file into text?" unless you also answer the question, "what does all that binary information *mean*?", because numbers can be used to represent quite literally any kind of information. And, to find out what it means, you have to understand what the thing that created the file was doing when it created it.

Comment: A great thanks for this. You ask me for text forms. What are the other text forms?

Comment: They are limited only by your imagination.

Comment: Can it be in alphabetical form instead of numeric? As you can see in .g file there are some words like tor.s, unit etc

Comment: Sure, but for those words you see, it's in that form to begin with, otherwise you wouldn't be seeing it that way. What about all the stuff that *doesn't* look like words? What "alphabetic form" would you propose for those?

Comment: Every word is written in binary form in that file. Just want to convert that binary value into its real alphabet form.

Comment: If "every word is written in binary form in that file", then it would be a text file. ASCII is what you use to encode text into numeric values, binary or otherwise. If you're not able to read it as a text file, then your assumption that "every word is written in binary form in that file" is clearly not true.

Comment: You tell me, it's your file. This is why you were repeatedly asked to provide sample output, because nobody can guess what the author of that file meant its contents to represent. You could replace `\00` with the word `"zero"` every time you came across it, for instance, but you wouldn't end up with anything particularly meaningful. You *can* convert anything into words, but unless you tell people *how* you want to do that conversion, you don't even have a programming problem yet, just a problem of not really knowing what you want to do.

Comment: Sure it can. Can you update your question with details of how to extract this information from your file? It'll be a relatively trivial operation once you've done that. See the edit to my answer for some insight into why what you're asking doesn't make sense to anyone.

Comment: You need to log in to edit your question, then you won't have to wait for it to be approved. But I still don't think you understand. In your edit, you say "then it write information further in some required sequence". *You need to specify exactly what this 'some required sequence' is*. You can't write a program to translate it until you know exactly what translation you need to do. A computer can only do what you tell it, and if you don't know exactly what to tell it to do, then it's not going to work.

Comment: In other words, you need to understand what every single byte in that file of yours means. Until you understand this, there's no point even beginning to talk about writing C programs to translate it.

Comment: Ok, skip it for awhile, can we convert that hexa code into text like which you have converted a hours before?

Comment: We are going round in circles. Define "convert into text", in this context.

Comment: As far as I know, the `b` (binary) mode turns off any processing and `"Ha!\n"` is always represented as 4 bytes. If you don't use the binary mode, then `\n` is converted to `\r\n` on Windows. It happens when reading files too: `\r\n` is transparently converted to `\n` only. The above implies you use `fprintf` to write to binary file; `fwrite` always writes literal data. For more information, see [Binary and text modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/FILE#Binary_and_text_modes).